# hide admin bar according to a post metadata

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post-meta

I know there are some questions are similar to my question but mine is a little different
I've added a post metadata to all post types called 'admin_bar_status'
then created a function that reads all types into a table with a toggle switch to update that metadata to 0 or 1
I did everything well but I have two problems :

when I switch the toggle , it doesn't changed until I pressed once again.

```
<?php
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    $i = 1;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="tableform" method="post">
            <table class="table-style" class="right">
                <thead>
                    <th>Post Type</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </thead>
                <?php
                // Loop through each post type
                foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

                    // Arguments for WP_Query (customize as needed)
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'post_status' => 'any',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all posts
                    );

                    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

                    // Loop through each post
                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        //while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        $the_query->the_post();

                        // Check if the post has the 'admin_bar_status' metadata
                        if (metadata_exists('post', get_the_ID(), 'admin_bar_status')) {
                            // Get the 'admin_bar_status' metadata
                            $admin_bar_status = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'admin_bar_status', true);
                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $post_type; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td align=center>
                                    <label class="toggle-switchy" data-size="sm">
                                        <?php
                                        if ($admin_bar_status == 1) {
                                        ?>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="example2" onchange="submitPostType('<?php echo $post_type; ?>')" checked>
                                            <span class="toggle">
                                                <span class="switch"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php
                                        } else {
                                        ?>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="example2" onchange="submitPostType('<?php echo $post_type; ?>')">
                                            <span class="toggle">
                                                <span class="switch"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            function submitPostType(postType) {
                var form = document.getElementById('tableform');
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = 'postType';
                input.value = postType;
                form.appendChild(input);
                form.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $post_type = $_POST['postType'];
        _update_post_type_metadata($post_type);
    }
}
```

also, the main problem is:
the function that reads that metadata can't hide the dmin bar for the specific page which has 'admin_bar_status'==0 or hide for all types!

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'set_admin_bar');

function set_admin_bar()
{
    // Get all registered post types
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        // Get the admin bar status for the current post type

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Get all posts
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $admin_bar_status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'admin_bar_status', true);
            // Hide the admin bar if metadata is set to 0
            if ($admin_bar_status === '0') {
                show_admin_bar(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing and hiding the admin_bar you need to use filter

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', function () {
    global $post;
    if (is_single() && "0" == get_post_meta($post->ID, 'admin_bar_status', true) {
        return false; // hide admin bar
    }
    return true; // show admin bar
});
```

Comment: your answer is the solution thanks so much :) but there is ) missing after true )